# Angular JWT refresh token

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement JWT with refresh tokens based on an external API and Angular. I wrote the following code

**TokenInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service'

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public authService : AuthenticationService ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
      console.log(`AddTokenInterceptor - ${request.url}`);      

      return next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          this.refreshToken()
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe(
              data => {
                return next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
              },
          ) 
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }));
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  } 

  private refreshToken(){
    return this.authService.refreshToken()
  }
}
```

**AuthenticationService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  public currentUser: string

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    ) { }

  login(username:string, password:string){
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', {username: username, password: password})
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access)
          localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh)
        })
      )
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')
  }

  getJWToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  }

  getRefreshToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
  }

  refreshToken(){
    let refreshToken : string = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'); 

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/', {"refresh": refreshToken}).pipe(
      map(data => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

**HomeComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TeamService} from '../../services/team.service'
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  teams; 
  constructor(private teamService : TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.teamService.getTeams().pipe(first()).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.teams = data.results
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error)
      }
    )        

  }

  login() : void {
    console.log(this.teams)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to refresh the token when a 401 response is returned, the following happens right now:

- Access token is expired;
- New one is request;
- Console shows the following error when rendering the home componenent with the 'teams' variable: `"You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."`

After that, when I refresh the page the teams variable is correctly loaded and can be used. My question: how can I refresh the token before the request is made so that the request can always be made with a valid access token? It seems that the mistake is in the `TokenInterceptor` but I can't seem to figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine except instead of subscribing inside the interceptor try to map the response in the pipe.

**Update**

As @ionut-t pointed in the comments there must be two changes:

- Replace `subscription` with a `switchMap` operator
- Return the observable in the `catchError` operator

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  console.log(`AddTokenInterceptor - ${request.url}`);      

  return next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
  .pipe(catchError(error => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
      return this.refreshToken()
      .pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(        // <-- map the response instead of subscribing here
          data => next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
        )
      )
      ...
```

Comment: You're right about the subscription but `map` won't work in this case (or at least not alone) because `next.handle` returns an observable. So please edit your answer and replace `map` with `switchMap`.

Comment: You’re right, I overlooked it. I approved your edit. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelD Using this the request to '/refresh/' is not made anymore

Comment: @SanderBakker in the `if else` statement you must return `this.refreshToken()`. See if that fixes your issue and if it is @MichaelD can edit his answer. Also, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60746089/11881804) for a slightly different implementation.

Comment: @ionut-t The return worked. Do you have an example of your authService used in the link you provided?

Comment: @ionut-t: Yes another overlook, I'll remove my answer if you want to post your own.

Comment: @MichaelD no need. I think your answer caught the issue and need it just a few fixes. Posting a new answer didn't make sense for me since you were almost there. Glad to help you.

Comment: @SanderBakker If the MichaelD answer helped you, please accept it and upvote it. Regarding the authService, I've created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ionut-t/bc477846b48455570a63b3b826e7e13f) where you can find the code. There are some changes though but the code is documented so you can easily figure it out. I've posted all the code so you need to go through it but maybe you can find something useful for other cases.

Comment: @MichaelD The answer misses the return statement, if you add that I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can't refresh the token for all 401 responses because if the user tries to login to your system using invalid credentials will also have a 401 response.

Usually, the HTTP response header that comes from the API has something that indicates that this client once was authenticated but now has an expired token. Typically, the response header has a property called token-expired or www-authenticate; you have to check this before starting the refreshes token process.

Code sample:

> **AuthInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { filter, switchMap, take, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private tryingRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    request = this.addAuthorization(request, token);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        const tokenExpired = error.headers.get('token-expired');
        if (tokenExpired) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        }

        this.authService.logout();
        return throwError(error);
      } else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    }));
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.tryingRefreshing) {
      this.tryingRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
      
     return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.tryingRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);
          return next.handle(this.addAuthorization(request, token));
        }));

    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(jwt => {
          return next.handle(this.addAuthorization(request, jwt));
        }));
    }
  }

  addAuthorization(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return httpRequest = httpRequest.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```

> **Refresh token**

> **This is just a sample method to show the share() approach.**

```
  refreshToken(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/auth/token/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(
        share(),
        map((authResponse) => {
          this.currentAuthSubject.next(authResponse);
          this.addToLocalStorage(authResponse);
          return authResponse.token;
        }));
  }
```